# Minikube failing to pull local docker image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to create a mapping for a gRPC service with ambassador, a load balancer. To deploy and map the service, I created a yaml file that has the following lines (among others):

```
containers:
      - name: grpc-pep
        image: enm10k
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
```

When I deploy it and run `kubectl get pods`, I get the following message:

```
NAME                                             READY     STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
ambassador-567f8c7c6-68bx6                       2/2       Running        3          3d
ambassador-567f8c7c6-c2n6z                       2/2       Running        3          3d
ambassador-567f8c7c6-kjznt                       2/2       Running        5          3d
grpc-pep-5f54b8d77b-f4l94                        0/1       ErrImagePull   0          3m
```

I am getting an ErrImagePull error message for the image I am trying to to access. enm10k is a dockerhub image, and I am under the impression that I should not be creating it. But, even when I *do* to create it, I get the following error message:

```
tex@tex-ThinkPad-P50:~$ docker build -t enk10k .
WARN[0000] Unable to use system certificate pool: requires building with go 1.7 or later 
Error checking context: 'no permission to read from '/home/tex/.cpan/build/CPAN-Meta-YAML-0.018-YA9MFT/lib/CPAN/Meta/YAML.pm''.
```

When I try to build it in a place that is not home directory:

```
$ docker build -t enm10k .
WARN[0000] Unable to use system certificate pool: requires building with go 1.7 or later 
Sending build context to Docker daemon 980.1 MB
Error response from daemon: unexpected error reading Dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder360563372/Dockerfile: is a directory
```

So, I cannot build the image, I cannot find it, and I am not sure how to approach it. I have set the minikube environment `$ eval $(minikube docker-env)` and I have used just about all policy variations for the `imagePullPolicy` in the yaml file.

I am not sure how to approach this - hopefully someone with more Docker knowledge can assist me.

Comment: docker pull enm10k doesn't work.. Maybe you need to define docker pull reponame/enm10k? Here I see a few images https://hub.docker.com/u/enm10k/ but you need to pull enm10k/grpc-hello-world for the grpc example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the `yaml` file, as it's missing repository name.

```
containers:
      - name: grpc-pep
        image: enm10k
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
```

If you go to [hub.docker.com](https://hub.docker.com/) and search for [enm10k](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=enm10k&starCount=0), you will see 3 repositories.
In your example, docker does not know which repo to pull.

The yaml files should look like this:

```
containers:
      - name: grpc-pep
        image: enm10k/grpc-hello-world
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
```

You can also check the documentation on how to get [gRPC and Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/grpc).